# looping over a try/catch block?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am trying to write a try catch block like the following, but put it inside a loop. My issue is that when i put it in a while loop, it runs x amount of times. i want it to stop when the first try is successful. but give the option to run up to 3 times.

```
    try {

            myDisplayFile();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            System.out.println("could not connect to that file..");

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    public static void  myDisplayFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner kin = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a file name to read from:\t");
    String aFile = kin.nextLine();

    kin.close();

    Scanner fileData = new Scanner(new File(aFile));
    System.out.println("The file " + aFile + " contains the following lines:");

    while (fileData.hasNext()){
        String line = fileData.next();
        System.out.println(line);
    }//end while
    fileData.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int max_number_runs = 3;
boolean success = false;

for( int num_try = 0 ; !success && num_try < max_number_runs ; num_try++ )
{
    try
    {
        /* CODE HERE */
        success = true;
    }
    catch( Exception e )
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int someCounter = 0;
boolean finished = false;
while(someCounter < 3 && !finished) {
    try {
        //stuff that might throw exception
        finished = true;
    } catch (some exception) {
        //some exception handling
        someCounter++;
    }
}
```

You can `break;` within a `try catch` block and it will exit the loop that it's in (not just the `try catch` block), but from a readability stand point, this posted code might be better.

`finished = true` should be the final line of the `try` block.  It won't throw an exception.  And it will only execute if every other line of the `try` block executed without an `exception`.  So if you get to `finished = true`, you didn't throw and exception, so you can toggle your flag and exit the loop.

Otherwise, if an exception is thrown, the `finished = true;` line won't execute.  You'll deal with the exception, then increment the `someCounter++` variable.

This is ideal from a readability standpoint because all possible `while` loop exits are marked in the conditional part of the `while` loop.  The loop will continue until either `someCounter` is too large, or `finished` returns true.  So if I'm reading your code, all I have to do is look through your loop for the parts where these variables are modified, and I can quickly understand the loop logic, even if I don't yet understand everything the loop is doing.  I don't have to hunt for `break;` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem correctly. Here's a way.

```
    int noOfTries = 0;
    boolean doneWithMyStuff = false;
    final int MAX_LOOP_VAL = 10;
    int noOfLoops = 0;

    while(noOfTries < 3 && noOfLoops < MAX_LOOP_VAL && !doneWithMyStuff) {

        try {

            // Do your stuff and check success

            doneWithMyStuff = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            noOfTries++;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {

            // Close any open connections: file, etc.

        }
        noOfLoops++;
    }
```